# Regex to allow only digits and "-" in WPF 2010

Tags: regex

I wrote Regex to allow only digits. It is `@"[0-9]"` and it works perfectly. But I would like to add a symbol "-" in regex.  I want to allow digits and "-". How to do it?)
I've tried such mask `@"[0-9]\{-}"`  but it allows nothing.

---

I have seen recently that if I input hyphen then my program does not understand as "hyphen". This is a reason why your all masks did not work. Nevertheless, they are all correct. Thanks a lot for your help. Now I will find how to read hyphen as "-" in WPF 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hypens (`-`) do not act like range specifiers at the beginning of a character set, so you can do this with the regex

```
@"[-0-9]"
```

or if, like in most regex engines, WPF allows character set shorthands in character sets, you can also use

```
@"[-\d]"
```

or, as the other answers mentioned, you can escape the `-` to put it in the regex, as in either of these two regular expressions

```
@"[0-9\-]"
@"[\d\-]"
```

Comment: none of these work? You can put a hyphen between characters but not before or after them?

Comment: no, when I try to input "-", then this mask does not allow hyphen.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I know for a fact that these regular expressions (or at least the third one) will match any digit or a hyphen. Are you sure these are actually regular expressions that you are working with?

Answer (score 2):

Escape it in the range like this:

```
@"[0-9\-]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with WPF 2010, but if it's like most other regex engines, you can write:

```
@"[0-9-]"
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are testing phone or fax numbers consisting of only digits and hyphens.

You may try `[\d\-]+` [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html). Note: to match a single digit or hyphen remove `+`.

Comment: it is very interesting, but the mask @"[0-9] works correctly and it allows to input only digits but other masks don't give a chance to input hyphen.